# Assume $b>0$. Show that the Lebesgue integral $\int^{\infty}_{1} x^{-b} e^{b\sin(x)} \sin(2x) dx$ exists iff $b>1$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Assume $b>0$. Show that the Lebesgue integral $\int^{\infty}_{1} x^{-b} e^{b\sin(x)} \sin(2x) dx$ exists iff $b>1$.

**Progress:** I canton when $b>1$ the integral really is finite but don't know how to show the reverse direction. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**

$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \int_{2k\pi +\frac{\pi}{8}}^{2k\pi +\frac{3\pi}{8}} e^{b \sin x}\frac{\sin 2x}{x^b}dx$$ diverges, by comparison with the harmonic series.

So the function is not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: (+1) It is interesting to point out that for $b=1$ the associated improper Riemann integral, instead, *is* convergent by Dirichlet's test, since $e^{\sin(x)}\sin(2x)$ is a function with mean value zero and $\frac{1}{x}$ is a decreasing function on $(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Good comment Jack! I'll modify.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Indeed, improper convergence for all $b\in (0,1].$